# Can I emulate strcpy using malloc?

Tags: c, c-strings

I'm trying to make a strcpy function from scratch for a class. While I could do it with a for loop and copy the individual characters, I think I could just make a swap using malloc and pointers to make it more efficient. Here's my code, but I've been getting a lot of confusing errors.

```
void notStrcpy(char s1[], char s2[]) { //copies string s1 into s2
char *s3 = (char *) malloc(strlen(s1)); //s3 is now an alias of s1
s2 = *s3;} //dereference s3 to dump s1 into s2
```

Why is this happening, and is there any way to make this code work the way I intended it?

Comment: No, absolutely not like that. You can't copy a string with the assignment operator. That's the whole point of `strcpy`. If the assignment operator supported string copying there would be no need for `strcpy`.

Comment: everything about this is wrong

Comment: "I've been getting a lot of confusing errors" - confusing for you? Imagine it from *our* end, as we can't even see the errors that are confusing you as you chose not to share them in your question. Regardless, what you appear to be trying is a fruitless endeavor, and some more studying on how pointers in C are used should be elevated on the agenda of your studies.

Comment: If you don't want a loop, you can use `memcpy`. But a loop is probably best. With `memcpy` you will need the string's length so add in a call to `strlen`, so what are you saving?

Comment: @Johnny Mopp: He already has a call to `strlen`. He just has to save the value and use it twice: for `malloc` and for `strcpy`.

Comment: @WhozCraig *s3 returned an int or a null variable which I didn't understand because I casted it.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm new to C, and pointers in C as I understand it are the same as object reference variables in java (except with primitive data types instead of objects), hence my confusion.

Comment: No, `s3` is not an alias of `s1`. It's a pointer to the initial element of an allocated character array that's *almost* long enough to hold the copied string that you never actually copy. Oh, and `strcpy` takes the source string as its *second* argument and the target as its first -- easy to remember once you realize it's the same order as an assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that: `strcpy` expects both chunks of memory to be ready - one for reading the string, and the other one for writing the string. Both addresses are expected to have enough memory for the actual content of a null-terminated C string.

On the other hand, `malloc` gives you a third chunk of memory (you need to allocate `strlen(s)+1`, but that's a completely different story). String copy algorithm has no use for that chunk of memory. On top of that, assigning parameters of a function has no effect on the values passed into your function, so `s2 = *s3` is not doing what you think it should be doing.

Long story short, `while ((*s1++ = *s2++));` is your simplest `strcpy` implementation.

**Note:** `malloc` could come in handy in an implementation of string *duplication* function, e.g. `strdup`. If you decide to give it a try, don't forget to allocate space for null terminator.

Comment: Thank you. My new function is as follows:

Comment: void totallyNotstrcpy(char s1[], char s2[]) {

Comment: void totallyNotstrcpy(char s1[], char s2[]) {

Answer (score 0):

@dasblinkenlight Thank you. My new code is as follows:

```
void totallyNotstrcpy(char s1[], char s2[]) {
int x = 0;
while (x < strlen(s1)+1) {
    s2[x] = s1[x];
    x++;
}
}
```

As a quick side question, how does your code snippet work? Doesn't the while loop need a condition?

Comment: That's terrible.  `strlen()` is O(n), so your `strcpy` is O(n^2).  You don't need to know the length of the string.  You just need to copy characters until you reach (and have copied) the NUL terminator, which is O(n).